# how to meke fl studio stop adding new tracks every time it loops

Tags: audio-recording, fl-studio, loop

i want to try loop recording on fl studio, i followed some tutorials on youtube and i got the hang of it but the problem is that fl studio adds a new track every time it loops

[image]

help me please

Answer (score -1):

I believe that's the way FL Studio works. Every new loop recorded on the playlist is a separate item. If you want all loops to be in one single track you should use edison to loop record instead